# how to design grapdb efficiently?

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j grapdb.While designing a graph db Node with 100 propeties is better or Node with some relations(from those 100 properties making some relations ) are beteer ?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend of what you will do with those properties, but most of the time you should split your node into multiple nodes.

Each node record have a fixed size in the node store, so if your node's data overflow it, Neo4j will save somes into the property store.
So to fully-read a node (on a return node, and on where clauses), it takes more times (obviously).

Moreover, it is more like the way graphs :)